# What / where are the foods required to get the 'Foodie' trophy?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

So far I have eaten:

Pork bun,
Ice Cream,
Noodle Bowl,
Dragon Kick,
Chicken Stick,
Herbal Tea
and Waffle Eggs.

I recall having a duck dish but I can remember exactly what it was.

This gives me 8 of the required 10 different foods and drinks.

What foods and/or drinks am I missing and where can I find them?

Remember - Man who never eat pork bun is never a whole man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more than 10 different foods or drinks found in the game. Here is a list:

- Chicken On A Stick
- Curry Chicken Balls (Next to the undercover HQ in North Point, next to Spicy Squid in Aberdeen)
- Dragon Kick
- Fish Dumpling Skewer
- Herb Tea
- Ice Cream
- Noodle Bowl
- Pork Bun
- Roast Duck
- Spicy Squid (Next to the Massage Parlor by Fish Market in Aberdeen)
- Waffle Eggs

You can find most of these in the `Night Market`. There are plenty of food stands, drink vending machines, and tea shops all around Hong Kong.

Here is a video guide by Predni showing you all different location of food and drinks: